# Compiling native_app_glue.c results in an invalid library file

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm cross-compiling a C++ library to Android. I'm using CMake as my build generator and I'm using the toolchain file provided in the NDK (called `android.toolchain.cmake`). Note, I'm on Windows.

I'd like to compile the `android_native_app_glue.c` source - also provided by the NDK - to a static library so I can later link it to my final application. After having an error, that said I'm missing the symbol `ANativeActivity_onCreate`, I've started investigating. `ANativeActivity_onCreate` is a function defined in `android_native_app_glue.c`, so I've looked at the compiled library using `nm -o libnative_glue.a` and it was quite surprising to see this:

```
libnative_glue.a:android_native_app_glue.c.o:0000000000000000 T ANativeActivity_onCreate
libnative_glue.a:android_native_app_glue.c.o:0000000000000000 t android_app_create
libnative_glue.a:android_native_app_glue.c.o:0000000000000000 t android_app_destroy
libnative_glue.a:android_native_app_glue.c.o:0000000000000000 t android_app_entry
libnative_glue.a:android_native_app_glue.c.o:0000000000000000 t android_app_free
...
```

Basically my functions are "there", but are zero-sized. I'm assuming they are thrown away at the next link, since they are not valid - looking at the next artifact with `nm` confirmed that.

The CMake snippet to compile the library is fairly trivial, but I'll provide it for completeness's sake:

```
add_library(native_glue STATIC "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c")
```

I have two pre-defined cache-entries for CMake, `ANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a` and `ANDROID_PLATFORM=24`.

What could cause this invalid library compilation?

Comment: For Android application, you must supply a shared library. You will find it easier not to use static libraries to build this shared library, but add all relevant sources to the shared one.

Comment: @AlexCohn I know, the final product is a shared library, but it was missing the `ANativeActivity_onCreate`. That's why I started looking into the static library compiled from this glue C source file and found that all the symbols are "invalid". Do you think it would make a difference if I didn't do this in multiple steps?

Comment: Building a NativeActivity is usually done via `libnative_app_glue.a`, see https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na. But the instructions there have never been updated for CMake, so it could be easier to add the `android_native_app_glue.c` file to your shared lib.

Comment: @AlexCohn So... Compiling directly to the target actually worked. I have no idea why. I'll investigate further. If you want, make it an answer, I'll accept it and maybe add additional information if I find out what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a NativeActivity is usually done via libnative_app_glue.a, see https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.

Unfortunately, the instructions there have never been updated for CMake, so it could be easier to add the android_native_app_glue.c file to your shared lib.

Answer (score 2):

The linker attempts to prune any unused symbols that come from non-whole static libraries, and `ANativeActivity` is not used directory but rather is intended for re-export.

You can either link `libnative_app_glue` as a whole archive, or use `-u` to prevent the symbol from being dropped.

With `-u`:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib -u ANativeActivity_onCreate native_app_glue)
```

With whole archives:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib -Wl,--whole-archive native_app_glue -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

I haven't actually tested either of these with CMake. The ndk-build equivalents are known to work though.

You might also be able to use an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries), which is the CMake flavor of whole archives.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(mylib -u ANativeActivity_onCreate native_app_glue)` would not work, since the `native_app_glue` library already has invalid entries for those functions (see my original post, `nm` output).
Also, for some reason, all my linker flags are passed through `ar`, which doesn't recognize any of these flags.

Answer (score 0):

A CMake object library fixes this issue nicely.

```
set(native_app_glue_dir "${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue")

add_library(android_glue OBJECT)

target_include_directories(android_glue PUBLIC ${native_app_glue_dir})
target_sources(android_glue PRIVATE
    ${native_app_glue_dir}/android_native_app_glue.c
    ${native_app_glue_dir}/android_native_app_glue.h
)

# NOTE: Linking against an object library requires at least CMake 3.12
target_link_libraries(foobar PRIVATE android_glue)
```

Now the symbol is properly exported.